# VSCode LaTeX nicematrix

Tags: visual-studio-code, matrix, package, latex, amsmath

I want to use the package "nicematrix" in VSCode, but it's not working the way I tried.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools,halloweenmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{vNiceMatrix}[first-row,last-row,first-col,last-col]
(I)&&x-&y+2z=1 \\
(II)-2x-5y+7z=0 & +2 \cdot (I)\\
(III)&5x+&y-3z=-11 & (-5) \cdot (I)
\end{vNiceMatrix}
\end{document}
```

The output should look like in this image, but it can't generate an  pdf-file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90ghW.png)

I get the following error:

```
Fatal Package nicematrix: Outside math mode. LaTeX [line 1, column 1]
(nicematrix) The environment {vNiceMatrix} can be used
(nicematrix) only in math mode (and not in \vcenter).
(nicematrix) This error is fatal.
```

The next big problem is, that a pdf can't be created:

```
Emergency stop LaTeX [line 256, column 1] 
:256: ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!Latexmk: Getting log file 'ombplus.log' Latexmk: Examining 'ombplus.fls 
Latexmk: Examining 'ombplus.log 
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets 
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
```

If I click on the problem with line 256, I get this message:

```
The Editor couldn't be open due to an unexpected error: The file "..." can't be read (Unknown (FileSystemError): TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'path' must be a string or Uint8Array without null bytes. Received 'file(...)/\x00'). Button: Try Again
```

How I can use the package "nicematrix" in VSCode?

I want to use the package "nicematrix", but VSCode doesn't recognise the package "nicematrix".
I downloaded it with the MikTeX-program: "miktex-pdftex" and this opens automically a "package-installer", if I include a new package in VSCode. Then I tried it with a download of this package in CTAN. It's not working this way.

Comment: Can you make a [mre] which allows us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools,halloweenmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{nicematrix}        @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz     I've got these packages in my document.

Comment: Please make a [mre], not just an unformatted list of packages in a comment. Edit your question to include a small test document, starting with a class until `\end{document}`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz   I didn't see the "edit" button. I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the missing math environment around your `nicematrix`, add for example `\[...\]` for an unnumbered equation.

I also think with `NiceArray` you'll get better alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools,halloweenmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{NiceArray}{l|rlll|l}
  \text{(I)}   &x    &-y   &+2z  &=1   & \\
  \text{(II)}  &-2x  &-5y  &+7z  &=0   & +2 \cdot \text{(I)}\\
  \text{(III)} &5x   &+y    &-3z  &=-11 & (-5) \cdot \text{(I)}
\end{NiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which math environments do I miss? Where do I find these?

Comment: @Celo For example the `\[ ... \]` I added in my answer